# cut for key-value pairs

Tags: text-processing, scripting

I am looking for an easy way to cut key-value pairs (where the key is unique and specified) from text, much like how `cut` can be used to cut a specified column in a CSV file.  The keys I'm looking for are not always in the same relative position in the line -- that is, using `cut` followed by `sed` won't do the trick, because they key I'm looking for is not always in the same `,`-delimited column.

The text in question is indeed CSV, but it so happens that the values are key/value pairs, delimited with an `=`.

For example, I might parse a file with the following three lines:

```
Foo=1, Bar=2, Baz=3
Bar=4, Foo=2, Baz=3
Bar=42, Baz=42, Foo=3
```

And I would like to cut this text to yield the key/value pair for a specific key.  If I was looking for `Foo`, then my desired output would be:

```
Foo=1
Foo=2
Foo=3
```

Ideally I would like a command-line tool that has similar syntax as `cut`, and can read both from stdin and from a file.

Is there such a tool?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`grep` can do this with `-o` option:

```
grep -o 'Foo=[^,]*' file
```

Comment: Probably need a boundary marker to avoid catching keys such as `NotFoo`

Comment: With a little tweaking, I got this to work with my actual use case.  I prefer this solution to the others posted simply because it involves less typing, and thus is more well-suited to quick hackery.

Comment: That's a feature I've wanted from `grep` for a long time. Did it creep in recently or haven't I reread the man page for too long?

Comment: @roaima one can add `\b` to not match `NoFoo`, so it would be: `grep -o '\bFoo=[^,]*'`. I don't know when `-o` was added, but it is there since I remember.

Comment: This would fail doing an exact search if you are looking for an specific key. For example if you have "FOO=1" and "MY_FOO=2" would match both lines. Add "^" if front of key to fix this: `grep -o '^Foo=[^,]*'`

Answer (score 3):

The `awk` solution to round up the list of alternatives:

```
awk -v RS=', ' -F'=' '$1=="Foo"' <file>
```

Treat each record to be delimited by `', '`, and split each record into fields on the `=` character (using `-F`) as well. Then it's just a matter of matching on the first field `$1`. The suggestion shown here is a simple string matching, feel free to use regexes, e.g. `$1~/\<Foo\>/`.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the complexity of your real-world situation, this `sed` command may be sufficient:

```
sed -n 's/^.*\(\<Foo=[^,]*\).*/\1/p'
```

Here's the worked example

```
FIELD='Foo'
sed -n "s/^.*\(\<${FIELD}=[^,]*\).*/\1/p' << xxEOFxx
Foo=1, Bar=2, Baz=3
Bar=4, Foo=2, Baz=3
Bar=42, Baz=42, Foo=3
xxEOFxx
Foo=1
Foo=2
Foo=3
```

Comment: @mikeserv where are multiple instances of the same key specified in the requirement?

Comment: Actually, the keys are unique in my use case.  This is stated in my OP.

Answer (score 2):

Given your example, a brittle solution could involve `cut`:

```
tr ', ' '[\n*]' <input | cut -sd F -f1-
```

...which would put each key/value pair on a separate line by `tr`ansforming the intervening commas and spaces into `\n`ewlines, and then `cut`ting out lines which don't contain an `F`. But that is a highly specialized example, and can only work if you can be sure an `F` only occurs in the wanted key/value pairs.

Otherwise, `sed` would be what I would use:

```
sed 'y/ ,/\n\n/;/^Foo=/P;D' <input
```

Which would also `tr`ansform intervening commas and spaces into `\n`ewlines, but then only `P`rint those key/value pairs which begin w/ the string `Foo=`. So long as the spaces are reliable separators, the above would work to portably print the `Foo` key/value pairs each on a separate line no matter how many times they might occur on an input line, and would print nothing else - even for lines which do not contain the key/values you want printed.

Comment: well, using `grep '^Foo='` instead of `cut ...` should give the expected result  (and would be pretty fast too).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a `grep` available with the `-o` option, this ought to do the trick as well:

```
sed -e 's/, /\n/g' | grep '^Foo='
```

That's using `sed` to replace every comma+space with a newline (breaking each key-value pair onto its own line), and then grep to search for only the 'Foo' key.

Test case:

```
printf "%s\n" "Foo=1, Bar=2, Baz=3" "Bar=4, Foo=2, Baz=3" "Bar=42, Baz=42, Foo=3" \
    | sed -e 's/, /\n/g' | grep '^Foo='
```